# Installing tensorflow causes an error on OS X?

Tags: python, python-2.7, deep-learning, tensorflow, tensorboard

I install the tensorflow on Python 3.5 successfully.

But I can't use the tensorboard due to the `BaseHTTPServer.py` which just support Python 2.x, 
then I install tensorflow on Python 2.7 it causes these problems:

```
Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', '/tmp/pip-K0gFNn-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', 
"[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-K0gFNn-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', '/tmp/pip-K0gFNn-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', 
"[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-K0gFNn-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', '/tmp/pip-K0gFNn-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', 
"[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-K0gFNn-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', '/tmp/pip-K0gFNn-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', 
"[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-K0gFNn-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', '/tmp/pip-K0gFNn-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', 
"[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-K0gFNn-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib'")]
```

Comment: Installing collected packages: setuptools, protobuf, wheel, numpy, tensorflow
  Found existing installation: setuptools 1.1.6
    Uninstalling setuptools-1.1.6:

Comment: Don't know how macs runs a command as admin but try running it with sudo or as admin :)

Comment: yujinkedeMacBook-Pro:~ root# sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.6.0-py2-none-any.whl

Comment: it seems that the pip can't uninstall the package.

Answer (score 3):

If you are having permissions issues or conflicts with other installed libraries, the [Virtualenv-based installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#virtualenv_install) is the easiest way to get TensorFlow installed.